# How to create an Index Match formula that pulls the answer from the most current column

Tags: excel, indexing, max, match

[image: Excel Sheet]

Hi I am trying to figure out how to create an index match, so that the information pulls from the most current date. 
Prices change weekly when buying wine and liquor.
So I understand Index Match, but I am trying to add MAX to it, to pull up the most current date and it isn't working.

What formula would I use?
Currently I have came up with something like this:

```
=INDEX(E3:P53,MATCH("Aplanta",B3:B55,0),MAX(E2:P2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few problems:

Firstly, `MAX(E2:P2)` returns the maximum value in that range, whereas you want the *Position* of the maximum value. You would find this by:

```
MATCH(MAX($E$2:$P$2),$E$2:$P$2,0)
```

And then put that position into the overall INDEX formula.

Next problem is E2:P2 is a mix of dates and text, which MAX won't operate on. They would all need to be dates for this to work.

Last and most significant problem is the formula bit I gave you above will always return the column with largest date, regardless of whether there is a value for that date or not.

What you *actually* want to find is the right-most value for each row. Now, you could do this entirely in one formula but it's very complex.

It would be much easier to put a helper column in your table before all the dates that shows the value from the latest date for each product. Then you can just do a simple vlookup on product name to return latest value stored in the helper column.

The helper column needs to return the value from the last non-blank cell in each row. If you insert a column before column E, moving your range of values to columns F:Q, this helper formula goes into D3 as an array formula, entered by pressing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` at same time:

```
=INDEX(F3:Q3,MAX(IF(F3:Q3>0,COLUMN($A1:$L1),0)))
```